# Pass data between two react components in MERN stack

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, react-hooks, mern

I am trying to build an E commerce web app where I handle the payments. First I need to take shipping information. I have successfully inserted data into mongo but I could not pass the data into another js right away from a single click.

Here is my create address page.

import React, { Component } from 'react'
import '../App.css'
import axios from 'axios'

export default class CreateAddress extends Component {

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        address: "",
        city: "",
        phoneNo:"",
        postalCode: "",
        country: ""
    }
}

handleInputChange = (e)=>{
    const {name,value} = e.target;
     this.setState({
         ...this.state,
         [name]:value
     })
}




onSubmit = (e)=>{
    e.preventDefault();

    const {address,city,phoneNo,postalCode,country} = this.state;
    const data = {
        address: address,
        city: city,
        phoneNo: phoneNo,
        postalCode: postalCode,
        country: country

    }

    console.log(data)

    axios.post("http://localhost:5000/address/save",data).then((res)=>{
        if(res.data.success){
            this.setState(
                {address: "",
                city: "",
                phoneNo:"",
                postalCode: "",
                country: ""}
            )
            alert("Shipping info added successfully");
            
            
        }
    })
}


render() {
    return (
        <div className="row wrapper">
            <div className="col-10 col-lg-5">
                <form className="shadow-lg" >
                    <h1 className="mb-4">Shipping Info</h1>
                    <div className="form-group">
                        <label htmlFor="address_field">Address</label>
                        <input
                            type="text"
                            id="address_field"
                            className="form-control"
                            
                            name='address'
                            value={this.state.address}
                            onChange={this.handleInputChange}
                            required
                            
                            
                        />
                    </div>

                    <div className="form-group">
                        <label htmlFor="city_field">City</label>
                        <input
                            type="text"
                            id="city_field"
                            className="form-control"
                            name='city'
                            value={this.state.city}
                            onChange={this.handleInputChange}
                            required
                            
                        />
                    </div>

                    <div className="form-group">
                        <label htmlFor="phone_field">Phone No</label>
                        <input
                            type="phone"
                            id="phone_field"
                            className="form-control"
                            name='phoneNo'
                            value={this.state.phoneNo}
                            onChange={this.handleInputChange}
                            required
                            
                        />
                    </div>

                    <div className="form-group">
                        <label htmlFor="postal_code_field">Postal Code</label>
                        <input
                            type="number"
                            id="postal_code_field"
                            className="form-control"
                            name='postalCode'
                            value={this.state.postalCode}
                            onChange={this.handleInputChange}
                            required
                            
                        />
                    </div>

                    <div className="form-group">
                        <label htmlFor="country_field">Country</label>
                        <input
                            type = "text"
                            id="country_field"
                            className="form-control"
                            name='country'
                            value={this.state.country}
                            onChange={this.handleInputChange}
                            required
                            
                        />
                                
                    </div>
                    
                    <button                            
                            id="shipping_btn"
                            type="submit"
                            className="btn btn-block py-3"
                            onClick={this.onSubmit}
                        >
                            &nbsp;SAVE                             
                    </button>
                    <button id="shipping_btn" type="submit" className = "btn btn-block py-3"><a href = "/confirm" style={{textDecoration:'none',color:'white'}}>PROCEED</a></button>
                    

                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

}

**Once I clicked the PROCEED button the data should direct into /confirm page**

Answer (score 0):

You can use history API to pass data as a URL and grab it into confirm page.

```
history.push(`/confirmPage?city=${city}&postalCode=${postalCode}`)
```

in confirmPage.js you will get that data as props

```
export default class ConfirmPage extends Component{
       render(){
         const {city, postalCode } = this.props.location.query;

         return (
            <div>{postalCode}</div>
         )
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use react-router to move between different routes in React. Also, in your code when you are sending a post request on `onSubmit` method, you are clearing the state information, which I think needs to be handled in the `confirm` page since you need the data in that page also.

Here's a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/statebetweenroute-qwtm0) demonstrating how you can send the information to another page, using react-router. I've used the functional components, but the concepts works for the class based components also.

note: also you should use `onSubmit` handler of the form to submit values rather than using the `onClick` method of the button. Otherwise you force users to click the button to submit the form.